# How can I log errors from a Stored Procedure in MySQL even when a ROLLBACK occurs?

Tags: mysql

I have the following code in a Store Procedure in MySQL (see below). When I don't put everything in a transaction, I can log errors on the Sproc directly into a table in the database. But when I put a START `TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`, and `ROLLBACK` around the entire thing, my logging no longer works. I'm guessing because it's rolling back my logging? How do I get around this?

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS condition 1
    @SQLState = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @SQLMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT; 
    SELECT CONCAT('Database error occurred, state - ',@SQLState, '; error msg - ', @SQLMessage) INTO @errorString;          

    CALL Log_Errors 
        (@errorString, 
        'MySprocName', 
        some_variable_1, 
        some_variable_2);

    ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

-- do some stuff
-- error happens somewhere in here

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a MyISAM table for logging. The MyISAM engine is not transactional. A row that is inserted into a MyISAM table stays inserted, even if a ROLLBACK is issued.

Using MyISAM for the logging table does introduce some other limitations. There's no enforcement of referential integrity (foreign key constraints). And no concurrent DML operations.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but for who needs an answer, you must call the ROLLBACK before the LOG and then call a COMMIT:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS condition 1
    @SQLState = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @SQLMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT; 
    SELECT CONCAT('Database error occurred, state - ',@SQLState, '; error msg - ', @SQLMessage) INTO @errorString;          

    ROLLBACK;
    CALL Log_Errors 
        (@errorString, 
        'MySprocName', 
        some_variable_1, 
        some_variable_2);
    COMMIT;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

-- do some stuff
-- error happens somewhere in here

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Could you provide a fixed version of the given example in the question? This would help others understand your solution better.

Answer (score 0):

When exiting, just do a `SELECT` and allow the calling application to handle logging like this:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    ...
    SELECT 
        CONCAT('Database error occurred, state - ',@SQLState, '; error msg - ', @SQLMessage) as @errorString,
        'MySprocName' as proc, 
        some_variable_1 as var1,  
        some_variable_2 as var2;

    ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
-- do some stuff
COMMIT;
```

The caller PHP/Python/whatever will catch the resultset and analyze it for errors. If error is found, it will call Log_Errors. That will also allow you to log to filesystem if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of rollback **code block** with ability to log the error to some other table without loosing the exception details in MySQL and throwing the error again after logging it. You should get diagnostics BEFORE the ROLLBACK and the logging part - AFTER.

```
# CREATE PROCEDURE AND OTHER DECLARE STATEMENTS HERE
# ....

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;

    ROLLBACK;

    SET @full_error = CONCAT('ERR:', @errno, '(', @sqlstate, '):', @text);

    CALL sp_logaction(@full_error); # Some logging procedure

    RESIGNAL; # Rethrow the error into the wild
END;
# PROCEDURE BODY WITH START TRANSACTION & COMMIT HERE
# .....
```